# Browser cache limit is per domain or all domains?

Tags: caching, browser, browser-cache

I'm newbie in web development. After read through some articles related to browser cache, know that there is default limit for all browser and user can set it themselves. But i still can't figure out the browser cache limit is per domain or total of all domain? I know that local storage is 5mb - 10mb per domain. How about browser cache?